# Apply lm across dataframe by factor

Tags: r, plyr

To begin: I realize there have been many questions asked on this topic and there are all sorts of ways to approach it (plyr, loops, data.table, etc.), but I am hoping someone might be able to help me with a very clean approach to this problem.

I have a dataframe ("df") with, let's say, 14 columns: 1) a factor column ("Factor"), 2) an independent variable column ("I"), and 3) 8 dependent variable columns ("D1:D10"). I would like to determine "lm" data for each combination of d~i, split by the factors. This dataset has NAs in it.

I've tried this approach where I define a function for 1 variable and try to apply over the whole dataframe:

```
onevariable <- function(i){ 
        by(df, df$factor,
         function(x) lm(d ~ i, data = x))
}

lapply(df[3:10], FUN = onevariable)
```

but I am getting an error that "variable lengths differ (found for 'i')". I've looked into other approaches, and understand how it can work with "mean" or other simpler functions, but I am admittedly too much of a noob to figure out how to apply some of the broad concepts to using "lm" on my dataset.

Basically, I am looking for a clean way to do this so that I can take the concepts and start applying them with my other work because I have yet to be able to take advantage of "by", split-apply-combine, etc. with this data so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Example subset of my data:

```
dput(example)
structure(list(Factor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("ALA010C1", "DEP010C1", "ECN010C1", "FEN020C1"
), class = "factor"), I = c(3.48321887, 1.446336943, 2.362627675, 
3.456785613, 3.070335007, 4.882472376, 2.026688629, 0.978996431, 
3.558568307, -5.336255193, -5.60451918, -4.735481333, -3.726817281, 
1.498296682, 2.930967205, 0.805149501, 1.080092548, 0.72616109, 
1.099140743, 2.41711586, 0.792410476, 0.98957854, -2.775840991, 
-0.06779079, 1.713816308, 2.729120928, 2.7707559, 1.060674462, 
0.946561155, 1.815599002, 1.127049531, 2.109024916, 2.712345138, 
1.815599002, 0.878352905, 0.72616109, 1.446336943, 0.830150804, 
0.924338019, 1.734019015, 0.805149501, 0.72616109, 0.935511319, 
0.712367768, 0.578836375, 1.070430637, 0.712367768, 1.693197021, 
1.370175582, 1.63419868, 0.640394268, 0.739766742, 0.530046211, 
1.089661999, 1.050822166, 0.779507071, 0.792410476, 0.753189762, 
0.766434989, 0.842420896, 1.333541449, 1.206386273, 1.84287342, 
1.108530483, 1.239722694, 1.703559808, 0.98957854, 1.398546279, 
2.367946836, 2.640259411, 1.010412627, 0.890048945, 1.485557656
), D1 = c(4.17438727, 4.766438334, 4.559126247, 4.127134385, 
4.317488114, 3.839452313, 4.40060302, 4.945207489, 4.051784948, 
5.49100171, 5.418320159, 5.409411414, 5.455321115, 4.430816799, 
3.998200702, 4.350277936, 4.859812404, 4.276666119, 4.043051268, 
4.085976313, 4.102643365, 4.182050143, 3.828641396, 5.92157842, 
4.158883083, 3.828641396, 3.860729711, 5.013963084, 5.033700567, 
4.40060302, 4.993828176, 4.151039906, 3.749504076, 4.483002552, 
7.66645609, 7.654443226, 7.320857814, 7.621684999, 7.725330038, 
4.543294782, 7.680637428, 7.686850772, 7.510704192, 7.674617497, 
7.556427969, 6.920177799, 7.558777533, 6.65544035, 7.288244401, 
6.914730893, 7.501082124, 7.495541944, 7.803843304, 7.823645931, 
7.644919345, 7.815610532, 7.849518807, 7.673223121, 7.835974582, 
7.769589825, 7.288586106, 7.260522598, 6.501289671, 7.337587744, 
7.528331767, 7.17395832, 7.74694896, 7.090076836, 6.478509642, 
5.647212123, 7.737834314, 7.887584032, 7.193685818), D2 = c(5.78, 
6.94, 6.64, 6.13, 5.82, 6, 6.92, 7.22, 5.22, 7.45, 7.25, 6.98, 
7.33, 3.96, 4.2, 3.95, 3.98, 4.05, 4.08, 4.07, 3.95, 3.84, 4.96, 
7.33, 5.78, 5.11, 5.24, 6.91, 7.02, 6.22, 6.8, 6.2, 5.22, 6.24, 
7.04, 7.43, 6.88, 7.3, 7.59, 6.86, 7.01, 7.37, 7.23, 7.07, 7.13, 
6.8, 7.42, 6.47, 6.66, 6.86, 7.21, 7.26, 7.62, 7.4, 6.98, 7.4, 
7.28, 7.2, 7.34, 7.22, 6.8, 6.81, 5.9, 6.95, 6.67, 6.67, 6.86, 
6.89, 6.65, 5.62, 7.055, 6.94, 6.71), D3 = c(0.598836501, -0.139262067, 
-0.314710745, -0.223143551, 0.058268908, -0.116533816, -0.223143551, 
-0.616186139, 0.182321557, -1.108662625, -1.049822124, -0.94160854, 
NA, 0.470003629, 0.182321557, 0.405465108, 0.78845736, 0.09531018, 
0.09531018, 0.182321557, 0.262364264, 0.2390169, 0.378436436, 
-0.139262067, 0.727548607, 0.770108222, 0.56815069, 0.39877612, 
0.343589704, 0.42199441, 0.438254931, 0.2390169, 0.165514438, 
0.524728529, 1.928618652, 2.312535424, 2.054123734, 1.859418118, 
1.791759469, 1.348073148, 1.982379829, 1.74745921, 1.795087259, 
1.774952351, 1.458615023, 1.40854497, 1.850028377, 1.324418957, 
1.736951233, 1.266947603, 1.885553349, 2.048982334, 2.1102132, 
2.117459609, NA, 2.302585093, 2.182674796, 2.210469804, 2.646174797, 
2.624668592, 2.071913275, 1.460937904, 0.88376754, 1.617406082, 
1.648658626, 1.335001067, 1.74745921, 1.32175584, 0.737164066, 
0.587786665, 1.064710737, 1.08180517, 1.098612289), D4 = c(-1.347073648, 
0.285178942, -0.579818495, -1.660731207, -0.798507696, -1.897119985, 
-0.84397007, -0.223143551, -1.609437912, -2.302585093, -2.207274913, 
-2.525728644, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.659260037, -2.302585093, 
-2.659260037, -2.525728644, NA, NA, -2.407945609, -2.302585093, 
-1.832581464, -1.771956842, NA, -2.525728644, -2.302585093, NA, 
NA, -3.506557897, -2.813410717, -2.525728644, -2.407945609, -2.525728644, 
NA, -2.407945609, -2.207274913, -2.995732274, -2.813410717, -0.385662481, 
-2.407945609, -2.813410717, -2.813410717, -2.813410717, -2.659260037, 
-2.525728644, -2.525728644, -3.218875825, -3.218875825, -2.040220829, 
-3.506557897, -2.659260037, -2.659260037), D5 = c(-1.937941979, 
-1.560647748, -2.111964733, -2.590267165, -1.826350914, -2.282782466, 
-1.826350914, -1.406497068, -1.443923474, -1.714798428, -1.660731207, 
-1.021651248, -1.609437912, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.021651248, 
-2.525728644, -1.973281346, -1.903808973, -2.385966702, -2.688247574, 
-2.419118909, -2.353878387, -2.465104022, -2.864704011, -2.603690186, 
-2.995732274, -2.882403588, -2.430418465, 0.438254931, 0.683096845, 
0.148420005, 0.841567186, 0.636576829, -0.28103753, 0.850150929, 
0.300104592, 0.703097511, 0.451075619, 0.625938431, 0.412109651, 
0.951657876, 0.78845736, 0.559615788, 0.019802627, 0.904218151, 
0.652325186, 0.802001585, 0.506817602, NA, 0.760805829, 0.667829373, 
0.932164081, 0.806475866, 0.774727168, 0.198850859, 0.2390169, 
-0.563874845, 0.765467842, 0, NA, 0.594431208, 0.009950331, -0.476424197, 
-1.505077897, 1.057790294, 0.620576488, 0.173953307), D7 = c(1.824549292, 
2.48490665, 2.332143895, 1.840549633, 2.32238772, 1.280933845, 
1.987874348, 2.985681938, 1.335001067, 1.098612289, NA, NA, NA, 
1.547562509, 1.252762968, 1.481604541, 1.360976553, 1.30833282, 
1.131402111, 0.916290732, 1.16315081, 0.993251773, 1.223775432, 
1.098612289, 0.916290732, 0.641853886, 0.875468737, 1.029619417, 
1.16315081, 1.029619417, 1.064710737, 0.832909123, 0.693147181, 
0.78845736, 5.765191103, 5.703782475, 5.472270674, 5.877735782, 
5.945420609, 5.135798437, 5.888877958, 5.111987788, 5.683579767, 
5.846438775, 5.897153868, 5.214935758, 5.762051383, 4.709530201, 
5.488937726, 5.209486153, 5.796057751, 5.869296913, 6.150602768, 
5.828945618, NA, 6.23636959, 8.196987927, 8.067776196, 8.457443187, 
5.950642553, 5.529429088, 5.641907071, 4.65396035, 5.572154032, 
5.65248918, 5.407171771, 6.070737728, 5.416100402, 4.229749199, 
3.478158423, 5.869296913, 6.104793232, 5.332718793), D8 = c(2.028148247, 
2.370243741, 2.714694744, 2.424802726, 2.433613355, 2.163323026, 
2.424802726, 2.4765384, 2.054123734, 1.85629799, NA, NA, NA, 
2.163323026, 2.00148, 2.48490665, 2.397895273, 2.140066163, 1.609437912, 
1.960094784, 2.014903021, 2.163323026, 2.312535424, 1.704748092, 
1.458615023, 1.16315081, 1.147402453, 1.740466175, 1.85629799, 
1.677096561, 1.686398954, 1.547562509, 1.280933845, 1.360976553, 
6.035481433, 5.993961427, 5.549076085, 5.926926026, 5.768320996, 
4.905274778, 5.905361848, 5.826000107, 5.908082938, 5.774551546, 
5.831882477, 5.135798437, 4.787491743, 4.86753445, 5.293304825, 
5.081404365, 5.707110265, 5.579729826, 5.805134969, 5.955837369, 
NA, 5.743003188, 5.991464547, 3.610917913, 5.828945618, 6.018593214, 
5.505331536, NA, 4.634728988, 5.521460918, 5.488937726, 5.068904202, 
5.480638923, 5.147494477, 4.248495242, 3.663561646, 5.669880923, 
5.843544417, 4.912654886), D9 = c(-2.488914671, -1.703748592, 
-2.538307427, -3.352407217, -2.3330443, -3.270169119, -2.198225078, 
-1.64506509, -1.807888851, -1.832581464, -1.771956842, -1.560647748, 
-1.660731207, -2.407945609, -2.882403588, -2.120263536, -2.207274913, 
NA, NA, -2.207274913, NA, -2.780620894, -2.103734234, -2.343407088, 
-3.381394754, -3.575550769, -2.946942109, -2.796881415, -2.748872196, 
-3.540459449, -2.995732274, -3.863232841, -3.816712826, -2.937463365, 
0.39877612, NA, -0.130108685, 0.548121409, 0.182321557, -0.62735944, 
0.604315967, -0.0965109, 0.620576488, 0.512823626, 0.58221562, 
-0.0965109, 0.678033543, 0.476234179, -0.151986357, -0.176737179, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.392042088, 0.21511138, NA, NA, 0.364643114, 
-0.336872317, -0.036663984, -0.703197516, -1.145703896, NA, 0.039220713, 
-0.40947313, -0.765717873, -0.823255866, -1.589635285, 0.774727168, 
-0.068278841, -0.134674903), D10 = c(1.481604541, 1.686398954, 
1.609437912, 1.360976553, 1.335001067, 1.098612289, 1.547562509, 
1.648658626, 1.30833282, 3.218875825, NA, NA, NA, 1.223775432, 
0.741937345, 1.029619417, 1.029619417, 0.875468737, 0.641853886, 
0.530628251, 0.832909123, 0.641853886, 1.386294361, 4.122283931, 
2.370243741, 1.916922612, 1.967112357, 3.33220451, 3.377587516, 
2.677590994, 3.335769576, 2.388762789, 2.028148247, 2.862200881, 
3.914021008, NA, 3.966511191, 4.087655574, 3.864931398, 3.42751469, 
4.043051268, 3.795489189, 3.891820298, 4.016383021, 4.286341385, 
3.514526067, 3.923951576, 2.939161922, 3.496507561, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 4.018183201, 3.929862924, NA, NA, 3.875359021, 3.218875825, 
3.658420247, 2.694627181, 3.511545439, NA, 3.222867846, 3.883623531, 
3.258096538, 2.557227311, 1.824549292, 3.706228092, 3.756538103, 
3.314186005), D11 = c(0.587786665, 0.875468737, 0.916290732, 
0.693147181, 0.587786665, 0.405465108, 0.832909123, 0.955511445, 
0.530628251, 2.63905733, NA, NA, NA, 0.641853886, 0.182321557, 
0.262364264, 0.09531018, 0.182321557, -0.105360516, -0.356674944, 
0.09531018, 0, 0.78845736, 2.624668592, 0.955511445, 0.530628251, 
0.587786665, 1.85629799, 1.916922612, 1.266947603, 1.85629799, 
0.993251773, 0.530628251, 1.410986974, 2.970414466, NA, 2.624668592, 
2.862200881, 2.850706502, 2.292534757, 2.917770732, 2.772588722, 
2.76000994, 2.884800713, 2.954910279, 2.406945108, 2.856470206, 
2.079441542, 2.564949357, 2.208274414, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.015534901, 
2.867898902, NA, NA, 2.970414466, 2.549445171, 2.442347035, 1.757857918, 
2.501435952, NA, 2.116255515, 2.923161581, 2.360854001, 1.435084525, 
0.832909123, 2.753660712, 2.809402695, 2.360854001), D12 = c(4.17438727, 
4.766438334, 4.559126247, 4.127134385, 4.317488114, 3.839452313, 
4.40060302, 4.945207489, 4.051784948, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Factor", 
"I", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", 
"D12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -73L))
```

Comment: What is `d` in your function.  Perhaps, `lapply(df[3:10], function(x)  by(cbind(df[1:2], x), df$Site, function(y) lm(y[,1]~y[,3], data=y))`  Please show an example data

Comment: There was an error in the previous code.  `lapply(df[3:10], function(x) {df2 <- cbind(df[1:2], x); by(df2[-1], df2[1], FUN= function(y) lm(x~., data=y))})` worked based on the example I created.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @akrun. The "d" in the function stands for the one of the dependent variable columns. When I tried your second code, I get an error, "0 (non-NA) cases". This is because some of my factors don't have any values for some of the dependent variables. I've run into this error before on this dataset...thoughts on how to get around that?

Comment: How about showing a reproducible example?

Comment: @akrun, Added subset of my data to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `if/else` condition to return NA if `all` the values in 'x' are NA or else do the `lm`

```
lst <- lapply(example[3:10], function(x) {
     df2 <- cbind(example[1:2],x)
    by(df2[-1], df2[1], FUN=function(y) 
       if(all(is.na(y$x))) NA else lm(x~., data=y))})
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Let me know what you think of the solution I came up with in the mean time.
 `library(reshape2)
m <- melt(df, id = c("Factor","I"))
m.cc <- m[complete.cases(m),]

fit <- function(data) {
  mod <- lm(value ~ I, data)
  setNames(coef(mod), c("intercept", "slope"))
}

results <- ddply(m.cc, .(Factor, variable), fit)`

Comment: @user2943039 That looks good.  You converted the wide to long format and used one of the group by options.